# Does there exist a continuous injection from $[0,1)$ to $(-1,1)$?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity, connectedness

Does there exist a continuous injective or surjective function from $[0,1)$ to $(-1,1)$ ? I know there is no continuous bijection from $[0,1)$ to $(-1,1)$ , but am stuck with only injective continuous or surjective continuous . Please help . Thanks in advance

Comment: Have the intervals the subspace topology induced by $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I've updated my answer to include both a continuous injection and a continuous surjection. $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

I think next two functions are continuous and:

$f(x) = x$ is injective but not surjective

$g(x) = x * \sin(1/(1-x))$ is surjective but not injective

Comment: I'm not really sure about g...maybe there is $\pi$ in the argument of sin

Comment: Nice $g$ for the surjective case! (it works because the sin will oscillate more and more rapidly, and closer and closer to $-1$ and $1$ as $x\rightarrow 1$).

Comment: @GianlucaFaraco   You don't need $\pi$ . As soon as $x$ is close enough to $1$, just continue until $x$ is multiple of $\pi / 2$, also 0 can be in the range..

Comment: @Pieter21 : How is $g$ surjective ?

Comment: @user228169, it not difficult, but I'm not telling either. Your question looks like homework, and you have to learn something by figuring it out yourself. The remark of Justin, and the definitions of surjective and continuous should be enough to figure it out.

Comment: Your first function, $f$, is not a function from $[0,1)$ into $(0,1)$, since it maps $0$ to a point not in $(0,1)$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy, range is (-1,1), not (0,1), so it's not a problem, otherwise you can indeed use your function. You'd also need this range modifier for $g$ if range were (0,1).

Answer (score 0):

$$
f(x) = x.
$$
This is a continuous injection from $[0,1)$ **onto** $[0,1)$ and so a continuous injection from $[0,1)$ **into** $(-1,1)$.

For a continuous surjection, let's do it piecewise.  Say a function $g$ is piecewise linear and $g(0)=0$, $g(1/2) = 0.9$, $g(3/4)=-0.9$, $g(7/8) = 0.99$, $g(15/16) = -0.99$, $g(31/32) = 0.999$, $g(63/64)=-0.999$, and so on.  The image of this continuous function is all of $(-1,1)$.